# Real-Complex type conversion within Exp / Acc

Tags: haskell, accelerate-haskell

I need to convert a real numerical value within the `Exp` or `Acc` type of the  [Accelerate library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/accelerate) to its corresponding `Complex` value, e.g.:

```
toComplex :: Exp Double -> Exp (Complex Double)
toComplex' :: Acc (Vector Double) -> Acc (Vector (Complex Double))
```

I tried to pattern match like

```
toComplex :: Exp Double -> Exp (Complex Double)
toComplex a = (\(r, i) -> constant $ r :+ i) $ (a, constant 0)
```

and suspect that `lift` or `unlift` as in https://www.acceleratehs.org/examples/mandelbrot.html might somehow solve this problem but can't figure out correct application of those.

For my attempt `ghc` complains that

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Exp Double’ with ‘Double’
      Expected type: Exp (Complex Double)
        Actual type: Exp (Complex (Exp Double))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be something like `toComplex = lift1 (:+ 0)`?

Comment: You are right, i overlooked this lift function. `toComplex = lift (:+ (constant 0))` solved my problem. Thanks!